# Help required in finding Prakash's house number!!

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation

The house number in Prakash's lane starts with natural numbers, i.e.  $1,2,3, \ldots$. The sum of all the house numbers on the left side of Prakash's house is equal to the sum of all the house on its right side. There are more than $100$ but less than $300$ houses on the right side of Prakash's house.
How many houses are there in the lane and also find the house number of Prakash?

My attempt:

Considering there are $n$ houses in total and the house number of Prakash is $x$,

$$x^2 = \frac{n(n+ 1)}{2}$$

And by given condition:

$$100<n-x<300.$$

How should i proceed to get the values of $n$ and $x$?

Comment: You should find a candidate between triangular numbers that are also square. One approach described here https://www.cut-the-knot.org/do_you_know/triSquare.shtml , however see @Arthur Vause  comment.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** $x^2 = \frac{(n)(n + 1)}{2} \Longrightarrow x^2 = \frac{n^2 + n}{2} \Longrightarrow 2x^2 = n^2 + n \Longrightarrow 2x^2 - n^2 = n$.

This then gives $x^2 - n^2 = n - x^2 \Longrightarrow (x - n)(x + n) = n - x^2 \Longrightarrow (n - x)(n + x) = x^2 - n$.

You know that $100 < n - x < 300$, so try to solve from here.

Comment: There don't appear to be any integer solutions satisfying $ 100 < n-x<300$

There is a solution if the total number of houses is between 100 and 300, or if the number of houses with numbers smaller than Prakash's is between 100 and 300.

Is one of those options what is meant in the question?

Comment: If on the right side there are houses with smaller numbers and on the left side houses with larger numbers, then solution exists (no. 204 in the lane of 288 houses).

Comment: The problem is I have found a possible solution as n=1681 and x = 1189 but it doesn't satisfy the inequality..

Comment: @Arthur Vause the way this question has been framed is creating confusion.